# LinearGradient not going transparent as end color

Tags: java, android, paint

I've set my LinearGradient like this

```java
TextPaint paintText = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paintText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paintText.setTextSize(size);
        paintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paintText.setShadowLayer(3f, 3f, 3f, Color.BLACK);

        int pL = bitmap.getWidth() / 100;
        int pT = bitmap.getHeight() / 100;

        StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(
                gagTitle,
                paintText,
                newCanvas.getWidth(),
                Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,
                1.0f,
                0.0f,
                false);

        int dummyHeight = mTextLayout.getHeight();
        Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, (dummyHeight * 2), Color.BLACK, Color.TRANSPARENT, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(shader);
        newCanvas.drawRect(new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), dummyHeight), paint);
```

I don't know why but at the end of generated gradient it's less brighter black other than being transparent.

Here is the result

[image: example]

Best Regards

Comment: The shader specifies dummyHeight * 2 but your rect is just dummy height, so you're displaying half of the gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LinearGradient coordinates are not relative, they are given in absolute values of the canvas grid.

Also it is not necessary to have a mirror boundary  in your case.

```
 Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, dummyHeight, Color.BLACK, Color.TRANSPARENT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```